# Undefined Offset when looking through an array to display values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, echo, undefined

Hey I am new to PHP and I am trying to take values from the user that were put into a form for a game. Every time the user enters text and clicks submit it should add it to the array. Every time it will show at the bottom of the page all the guesses currently in a ordered list until the user gets the right answer and wins.

```
<?php

    $count =0;

    $guesses = array();

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {   
            $count = $_POST['count'];
            for($r =0; $r < $count; $r++)
            {
                $guesses[$r] = $_POST['word'];
            } 
 ?>
    <h3>Guess the word I'm thinking</h3>
        <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method = "post">
            <input type = "text" name = "word" value = "<?php echo $tell; ?>"/>
            <input type = "hidden" name = "count" value = "<?php $count +=1;?>"/>
            <input type = "submit" name ="submit" value = "Make a Guess"/>          
        </form>

    <ol>
        <?php

            for($t=0; $t < $count; $t++)
            {
        ?>
        <li><?php echo $guesses[$t];?></li>

        <?php       
            }

        ?>
        </ol>
```

I keep getting a Undefined offset: 0. I did some reading and I know it has something to do with either me filling the array wrong or calling the index wrong. Hope you can help show me how to resolve this problem. Thank you.

The output would be similar to:

Your guesses:
1. blue
2. red
etc

Comment: your problem is this: `<?php $count +=1;?>`, you add 1 to your count and in the final for loop, it's trying to access an undefined offset.

Comment: btw, why don't you use sessions? then you must not send the count back to the server. use `session_start()` and `$_SESSION["variable"]`to store and retrieve data.

Comment: Our teacher for the game doesnt want us using sessions yet

Comment: How do i fix that problem? when a new guess is made it needs to increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look if you don't want to use Session variable then you have to set the values enter by the user in the hidden input tag. Below is the code you might required to get your specific result:

```
<?php 
    $guesses="";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   
        $guesses= $_POST['count']." ".$_POST['word'];
    }
?>
   <h3>Guess the word I'm thinking</h3>
   <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "word" value = "Word"/>
     <input type = "hidden" name = "count" value = "<?php echo $guesses;?>"/>
    <input type = "submit" name ="submit" value = "Make a Guess"/>          
   </form>

  <ol>
     <?php

        $count = explode(" ", $guesses);
        foreach($count as $val)
        {
            if($val!= ''){
    ?>

            <li><?php echo $val;?></li>

    <?php       
            }

        }

    ?>
    </ol>
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I can easily switch that up a little bit.

Comment: Also what does this do exactly?
   
        $guesses= $_POST['count']." ".$_POST['word'];

Comment: and this? $count = explode(" ", $guesses);
        foreach($count as $val)
        {
            if($val!= ''){

Comment: $guesses= $_POST['count']." ".$_POST['word']; is used to extend the guesses entered by the user every time he submit the form.

And $count = explode(" ", $guesses); foreach($count as $val) { if($val!= ''){... this code is user to break a guess string into array and display it at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

Problem was that you foremost did not echo the $count in your form, you simply incremented it. So the post variable would be empty. Also, increment it after you add to the array instead of in the post.

```
<?php
    if( !isset( $count ) ){
        $count =0;
    }
    $guesses = array();

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
            $guesses[$count] = $_POST['word'];
            $count++;
    }
?>
<h3>Guess the word I'm thinking</h3>
<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "word" value = "<?php echo $tell; ?>"/>
    <input type = "submit" name ="submit" value = "Make a Guess"/>          
</form>
<ol>
    <?php

        for($t=0; $t < count( $guesses); $t++)
        {
    ?>
        <li><?php echo $guesses[$t];?></li>
    <?php       
        }

    ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: we bring it to ourself so the variables do not reset

Comment: No error but it does not print any of the guesses out

Comment: Try it now. Also, the variable $tell seems to be undefined?

Comment: I forgot to send the variable declaration

Comment: I need to use the hidden input to increment the count by 1. Also It game a function error for $count($guesses)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$guesses = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    if($_POST['guesses'] != '')
        $guesses =  explode('|', $_POST['guesses']);

    if(trim($_POST['word']))
        $guesses[] = trim($_POST['word']);
}

?>
<h3>Guess the word I'm thinking</h3>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name= "word" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="guesses" value="<?php echo count($guesses)? implode('|',$guesses):''; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make a Guess" />          
</form>
<ol>
<?php foreach($guesses as $guess) { ?>
            <li><?php echo $guess;?></li>
<?php   }  ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: closer. the count starts 1 ahead so 1. ha 2. hg 3.  .. there should be no three unless person clicks submit, also i got an error. undefined ofset

Comment: also it does the list even when there are no input, if the field is black and the user clicks submit it shouldnt count

Comment: its very close, works, just if the user tries to send nothing through it should not do the list another spot